# mvvmcross Init method is not called if I inherit froma base ViewModel which is derived from MvxViewModel

Tags: mvvmcross

First I'm using `mvvmcross version 3.0.13`. When a class is inherited from a base class, which is inherited from `MvxViewModel`, the Init method won't be called from IoC. Current ugly workaround is to call the Init in the constructor. Could this be a bug or is there another pattern to use?

In both classes (base and child of that base) it won't be called. For example:

```
public class BaseViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    protected CDataImportService DataImportService { get; private set; }
    protected CSettingService SettingService { get; private set; }
    protected CDataService DataService { get; private set; }
    protected CDocumentService DocumentService { get; private set; }

    public BaseViewModel(IDataService objDataService, IDataImportService objDataImportService, IDocumentService objDocumentService, ISettingService objSettingService)
    {
        DataImportService = (CDataImportService)objDataImportService;
        SettingService = (CSettingService)objSettingService;
        DataService = (CDataService)objDataService;
        DocumentService = (CDocumentService) objDocumentService;
    }

    public void Init()
    {
        Mvx.Trace("Init called in {0}", GetType().Name);
    }
}

public class DocumentsViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public MenuViewModel(IDataService objDataService, IDataImportService objDataImportService, IDocumentService objDocumentService, ISettingService objSettingService)
        : base(objDataService, objDataImportService, objDocumentService, objSettingService)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: The `Init` should be called from https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross/ViewModels/MvxViewModelExtensions.cs#L17 if the default view model locator is used. From your description, I' not sure what your view model setup is - eg which class has `Init` - the base or the child? Can you edit your question to include more information (working sample code preferred)

Comment: Hi Stuart, i edited my question hope it es now clearer, thanks a lot

Comment: Can I also ask which platform or platforms you are testing on - will try to reproduce

Comment: Sorry yes sure, developing with VS2012+MonoDroid (latest stable version), App compiled & deployed against API Level 17 droid x86 emulator (with haxm)

Comment: Thanks - I've just tried this with a similar setup using both the base class and the child class - using a method `public void Init() { Mvx.Trace("Init called in {0}", GetType().Name);}`. In both cases `Init` was called during navigation. What does your navigation call look like - is it just normal `ShowViewModel`?

Comment: Hmm interesting, i updated the code part and tested this also, here the Init is not called :-/

Comment: What does your navigation call look like - is it just normal ShowViewModel?

Comment: I have MainViewModel (which is currently directly inherited from MvxViewModel - my intent is to extend all my ViewModels from the BaseViewModel), here in the constructor of that MainViewModel I'am loading all the viewmodels to their public properties with MvxConstruct, e.g. SettingsViewModel = Mvx.IocConstruct<DocumentsViewModel>();... These all viewmodels constructed in MainViewModel i'm consuming in my droid project in dynamic frames. I do not navigate to this viewmodel with ShowViewModel because these will be binded in Fragments

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IOC on it's own does not call the Constructor-Init-Reload-Start sequence.

IOC is a general C# service, and only calls the constructor part.

If you want the entire sequence called then you can access this via the IMvxViewModelLoader object - e.g `Mvx.Resolve<IMvxViewModelLoader>().LoadViewModel(MvxViewModelRequest<MyViewModel>.GetDefaultRequest(), null);`

By default, this will use the Default ViewModel Locator to create a view model instance - https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross/ViewModels/MvxDefaultViewModelLocator.cs

---

If it helps, for some more information:

- mvvmcross IOC is described fully in https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/Service-Location-and-Inversion-of-Control
- view model location is briefly discussed in https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/Customising-using-App-and-Setup

Comment: Thanks a lot, it helped. The doc about mvvmcross ioc i read allready before, it is really short und gives a really good introduction to that. There is a minor typo in your above answer, should be ...Resolve<IMvxViewModelLoader>()... thanks again :)! update: Sorry was not able to vote ab... not enough points :D I'm new in stackoverflow...